# Convert MySql query into MSSql query

Tags: mysql, sql-server

Here is my MYSQL query and I want to convert this into MSSQL. I saw some answers to do that using Microsoft SQL Server Migration Assistant for MySQL.

But since my PC is having some issues with installation of this application, I could not perform it. Can some one help me to convert the MYSQL query into MSSQL query?

Here is my query :

```
SELECT
RegNo,
MAX(IF(Subject = 'CMIS 1113', Eligibility, NULL)) AS `CMIS 1113`,
MAX(IF(Subject = 'ELTN 1113', Eligibility, NULL)) AS `ELTN 1113`,
MAX(IF(Subject = 'IMGT 1113', Eligibility, NULL)) AS `IMGT 1113`
FROM table_name 
GROUP BY RegNo
```

Comment: Please show what have you tried sofar.

Comment: Also, what version of sql server?

Comment: Since I am new to MSSQL I dont know to write complex queries.When I paste the same query In SQL Server Management Studio, it says that there is a syntax error around the "if " statement.I don not know how to change it according to MSSql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT RegNo,
       max(CASE WHEN Subject = 'CMIS 1113' THEN Eligibility END) AS [CMIS 1113],
       max(CASE WHEN Subject = 'ELTN 1113' THEN Eligibility END) AS [ELTN 1113],
       max(CASE WHEN Subject = 'IMGT 1113' THEN Eligibility END) AS [IMGT 1113]
FROM table_name 
GROUP BY RegNo
```